# Facebook Login is not returning error when logging in with an under age user on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm using Facebook Login on an iOS app which is made for people 18 years old or older.

I created a 14 year old test user on developers.facebook.com to check if my error handling is correct.

I also configured the age restriction as 18 years or older on my app's settings page on developers.facebook.com.

When logging in on my app on iOS I expected an error to be returned by the Facebook Login module, however no error is returned and a valid token is returned instead. If I send this token to my own backend server it identifies that the user's age is less than 18 and sends me back an error message, but in my experience in other apps I usually could rely on the Facebook SDK telling me the user is under age.

Is this behavior correct? Might it be a bug on the Facebook Login iOS SDK?